# google crawling errors from links that do not exist

Tags: http-status-code-404, web-crawler

In my google webmasters account, google shows that I have crawling errors that are caused by links to pages that do not exist (404 not found). But when I look at the source pages that are accused of having these broken links, there are no such links in them.
As of now, I have 6 404 errors in sitemaps and 28 in the rest of my site.

for example, the address http://www.webdesk.co.il/articles.php?id=13 do not exist. However, Google indicates that I have 3 pages that link to this address:

- http://www.webdesk.co.il/sitemapgen.php
- http://www.webdesk.co.il/articles.php?t=css
- http://www.webdesk.co.il/articles.php?id=17 (this address dont even
  exist)

[image: google webmaster crawling errors tool]

if you'll open each of these pages, you'll see that they do not have such links in them.

I thought this may be a result of an old crawling that was not yet updated, but those pages dont exist for over than 6 months, and Google indicates that all the crawling results are up to date (Dec 22 2012).

[image: crawling is up to date, according to google]

Why do I keep getting these 404 errors by Google?

Comment: webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I was not aware of this website @KevinDTimm. is there a way to remove this question in that case?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I have found that those pages are being linked from an outside source(s). I was able to fix the problem using multiple permanent redirects (using apache's redirectMatch). I still dont know why it was showing these links inside my sitemaps, but this was also fixed by the redirects.